# C "if" statement is not printing an output

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm sorry if this has been asked many times before. I'm a beginner coder and I'm supposed to find the coldest and warmest overall temperatures of a group of lakes. My "if" statements are not printing an output. I was wondering why this may be? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
void
overallColdestWarmest()
{
    printf("\n----- PART FOUR -----\n");

    double a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1;

    a1 = temp[0][(int)entries[0][0]];
    b1 = temp[1][(int)entries[1][0]];
    c1 = temp[2][(int)entries[2][0]];
    d1 = temp[3][(int)entries[3][0]];
    e1 = temp[4][(int)entries[4][0]];
    f1 = temp[5][(int)entries[5][0]];

    if(a1 < b1 && a1 < c1 && a1 < d1 && a1 < e1 && a1 < f1)
    {
        printf("Lake Superior has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", a1);
        date(entries[0][0]);
    }
    else
    {
        if(b1 < a1 && b1 < c1 && b1 < d1 && b1 < e1 && b1 < f1)
        {
            printf("Lake Michigan has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", b1);
            date(entries[1][0]);
        }
        else
        {
            if(c1 < a1 && c1 < b1 && c1 < d1 && c1 < e1 && c1 < f1)
            {
                printf("Lake Huron has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", c1);
                date(entries[2][0]);
            }
            else
            {
                if(d1 < a1 && d1 < b1 && d1 < c1 && d1 < e1 && d1 < f1)
                {
                    printf("Lake Erie has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", d1);
                    date(entries[3][0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(e1 < a1 && e1 < b1 && e1 < c1 && e1 < d1 && e1 < f1)
                    {
                        printf("Lake Ontario has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", e1);
                        date(entries[4][0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(f1 < a1 && f1 < b1 && f1 < c1 && f1 < d1 && f1 < e1)
                        {
                            printf("Lake St. Clair has the overall coldest temp of %.2lf on .\n", f1);
                            date(entries[5][0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if two (or more) values are equal?

Comment: Try outputting all the values stored in a1-f1 right before your if statements, and go from there. That way you can see if the logic is being performed properly. Also, you should be using an "else if" statement, instead of a bunch of encapsulated if statements.

Comment: Use `else if () { … }`. rather than `else { if () { … } else { … } }`; it stops your code wandering off the RHS of the page.  The hard-coded names for the variables is suspicious — surely you have the names in an array.  And couldn't you sort the array?  Maybe you haven't covered structures yet; this cries out for a structure (one copy per lake).  Are the temperatures for each lake sorted so that the coldest temperature is in element 0 of the array for the lake?

Comment: Edit the question to include a [mre].